# how do I install both neovim and vim plugins which are in the same .vimrc file?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I'm using neovim and would like to know how to install both `neovim` and `vim` plugins which are in the same `.vimrc` file?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that for one or the other you would have a `~/.vimother` instead of the usual `~/.vimrc` and then launch that one or the other via `$vim -u ~/.vimother` possibly via a shell alias or function. That would keep the vim stuff separate from the neovim stuff.